# How can I take my PHP script name out of URLs? htaccess rule isn't working.

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a PHP script which accepts some query string parameters. However, I want the user to call it without including the script name e.g. `example.com/?foo=bar`.

I've tried writing a mod_rewrite rule, but it redirects the user, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rename the script to `index.php`, accessing `example.com/?p=asd&p2=dsa` should work.

For the RewriteRule, make sure you don't have [R] after it.

Comment: I'll have some problems with changing the links in my code, but if that's the only solution, I'm okay with it.

Comment: Rewrite rules should work as well. What's your rule?

Comment: I tried a lot of things, but the one I'm using right now is RewriteRule ^?(.+) da.php [R=301]

Comment: Damn it, that works. I blame nobody for me, being so stupid, but I really couldn't find a SINGLE normal HTACCESS tutorial/guide. The only way was to Google a bit and find some easy solution, but nobody explains anything, they just give you this thing, which leads to you not understanding and copy-pasting like a complete idiot..

Comment: A good tutorial is http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php